docker-in-docker (DIND) connection unavailable when reuisng the same node in Kubernetes
We are facing a rather odd problem when trying to use DIND in our Jenkins pipelines. For this issue I don't think that Jenkins itself is relevant but rather the container setup.
We have a definition that looks like:
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  spec:
    nodeSelector:
      role: e2e_only
    tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: e2e_only
        operator: Equal
        value: "true"
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    containers:
      - name: deploy-toolbox
        image: 999999.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/deploy-toolbox:latest
        command: ['tail', '-f', '/dev/null']
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: DOCKER_HOST
            value: 'tcp://localhost:2375'
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: '100Mi'
            cpu: '100m'
          limits:
            memory: '2Gi'
            cpu: '2000m'
      - name: docker-daemon
        image: docker:27.2.2-dind
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
          - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
            value: ''
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: '6Gi'
            cpu: '4'
          limits:
            memory: '14Gi'
            cpu: '8'

The node selector makes sure we always run on a subset of K8s nodes that we have on an autoscaling group, again this I don't think is super relevant but trying to give a full picture.
The first time one of this nodes recieves a job the execution runs flawlessly and the connection to the docker daemon is succesful and we can do all the operations like docker build. The problem arises on the subsequent runs, if a new job is scheduled and the node has already been used it will always return an error: ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?.
I have also tried using the socket instead of the tcp connection, but the result is exactly the same. I have managed to pull some logs from the EC2 instance that is running this containers but unfortunetly it doesn't tell me much (at least to me, perhaps someone can make more sense of it).
[  260.347491] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth7b897a8: link becomes ready

[  335.556417] docker0: port 3(veth3a3f68f) entered disabled state

[  335.582976] veth4c4f652: renamed from eth0

[  335.671229] docker0: port 3(veth3a3f68f) entered disabled state

[  335.693756] device veth3a3f68f left promiscuous mode

[  335.714739] docker0: port 3(veth3a3f68f) entered disabled state

[  353.895434] docker0: port 2(veth622c08f) entered disabled state

[  353.899401] vethde6067b: renamed from eth0

[  353.973855] docker0: port 2(veth622c08f) entered disabled state


Using different version of dind and the UNIX socket connection, all results are the same. Rebooting the underlying EC2 instance "fixes" the issue every time, so it looks like there is some leftover from the process that prevents the connections afterwards.
I have also tried running docker-compose down --rmi local --remove-orphans or using the --remove-orphans on all the commands in case there was something dangling, but since the dind is in a container this should never be a problem since the daemon should be a new one.

Please refer Assigning Pods to Nodes official document which may helps to resolve your issue And also refer this open github issue for further information

The problem is not spinning the new pod, nor the containers. But rather the connectivity between containers. The pod gets assigned inside the correct node and both containers run for a few seconds until the docker error is thrown.

Apparently the issue was timing related. We have added a small wait time and this solved the issue. The first run was slower, I imagine that due to initialization. By adding some wait the resolution of the dind address is now succesful.
